# How to define a symbol similar to Yinyang?

Tags: symbols

I need a math symbol which

1. is similar to Yinyang (as follows) but without the two dots
   [image]
2. and has the same size as `\bullet`.

A MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

**Then how to define it?** Any help is welcome!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139769/why-is-there-a-light-gray-border-with-the-tikz-fill-command

Comment: Did you at least *try*?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192765/36296

Comment: This is a record as the shortest possible mwe. lol

Comment: @giusva Nah, it could be even shorter. See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/123901/79198 for some tips :)

Comment: @samcarter Ok, how to throw years spending learn good practices of writing LaTeX. :)

Comment: @giusva Well, it is for a good cause :) My favourite code golf: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/159718/79198

Comment: @Andreas Storvik Strauman Yes, I tried it but failed, sir.

Comment: @samcarter Only now I understood where I had already read your nickname... you are the creator of tikzducks!!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using TikZ. Code for the symbol was obtained from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139776/128068), and modified to match the size of `\bullet`. The size of the symbol is also scalable depending on your font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\customyinyang}[1][1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#1*0.07]
      \draw[line width = #1*0.05mm,transform canvas={yshift=0.02cm}] (0,0) circle (1cm);
      \path[fill=black,transform canvas={yshift=0.02cm}] (90:1cm) arc (90:-90:0.5cm)
                        (0,0)    arc (90:270:0.5cm)
                        (0,-1cm) arc (-90:-270:1cm);

    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

Text \customyinyang[1] $\bullet$

\LARGE Large text \customyinyang[1.8] $\bullet$

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

A version which scales automatically based on font size. As requested in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\customyinyang}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.45]
      \draw[line width = 0.05ex,transform canvas={yshift=0.12ex}] (0,0) circle (1ex);
      \path[fill=black,transform canvas={yshift=0.12ex}] (90:1ex) arc (90:-90:0.5ex)
                        (0,0)    arc (90:270:0.5ex)
                        (0,-1ex) arc (-90:-270:1ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

Text \customyinyang~$\bullet$

\Huge Huge text \customyinyang~$\bullet$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 nice answer! A small suggestion: If you use a unit based on the font size, e.g. `ex` the size would automatically scale. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413081/36296

Comment: @samcarter could you give a specific answer in which the symbol changes with the font size?

Comment: @Kuttens Done :)

Comment: By the way what's your real name? I'd like to show thanks to people who help me a lot on latex when writing my book. Also, how do you read your surname?

Answer (score 7):

As asked in [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431737/how-to-define-a-symbol-similar-to-yinyang/431741?noredirect=1#comment1081983_431741) here a version based on [Myles answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431741/36296) which scales the size of the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\customyinyang}{%
    \scalerel*{%
        \tikz[anchor=base, baseline]{%
            \draw[line width = 0.01em] (0,0.26em) circle (0.2em);
            \path[fill=black] (90:0.46em) arc (90:-90:0.1em)
                              (0,0.46em)    arc (90:270:0.2em)
                              (0,0.06em) arc (-90:-270:0.1em);
        }%
    }{\bullet}%
}

\begin{document}


{\Huge $F  \customyinyang \bullet$}   

{\normalsize $F \customyinyang \bullet$}   

{\tiny $ F \customyinyang \bullet$}   


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can increase o decrease the size of the symbol with the command `\Yiyang` with the coordinates of the points and of the circles. After with `circle (.25cm)` you can create a big, small o little bullet changed the value of `(.25cm)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\Yiyang}{\tikz{\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) circle (.25cm);
\fill[black] (0cm,.25cm) rectangle (-.25cm, -.25cm);
\end{scope}
\fill[black] (0,0.125) circle (0.125cm);
\fill[white] (0,-0.125) circle (0.125cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (.25cm);}
}
\newcommand{\newbullet}{\tikz\draw[black,fill=black] (0,0) circle (.25cm);
}

\begin{document}
Text \Yiyang and text! \ldots and \newbullet

\end{document}
```